# Custom edit text Android locates wrongly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to build a custom edit text. But the problem is the icon didn't locate rightly. I want these two to locate in the center. Where am i wrong?

[image]

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="34dp"
        >
        <!-- left is icon size + 2x side padding around icon-->
        <!-- 18 + 8 + 8 -->
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp"
                android:topRightRadius="6dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: post your  xml where you are using above drawable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#71B9DE">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/test"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/bca"
        android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> @drawable/test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#AAAAAA" />
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="34dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="6dp"
                android:radius="6dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="6dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#BBBBBB" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]